Flutter error: failed processing manifest, resource xml/file_paths not found
I ran the project on a new computer, after running the commands: flutter pub for dependencies, and I get this error:
Terminar error
Flutter version : 3.24.3
Dart version: 3.5.3
Someone who can help me, thanks.
I found in a post that you can fix the problem by deleting the provider tag from the AndroidManifest.xml file, but when I try to run the project it is generated again and shows me the same error.
AndroidManifest.xml
<application
        android:name="android.app.Application"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="mecamovil" >
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mecamovil.app.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
        .
        .
        .
 />

